# How can i invoke a lambda function that involves spring cloud feign from an SQS trigger

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-feign

I need to invoke an AWS lambda function using an SQS trigger. 
The lambda function needs to include spring boot features - because it needs to transform the message from SQS into another input form and then call an external REST API using spring cloud feign.

I'm supernew to spring & lambda so I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

I would like to understand if my expected workflow is supported by spring and aws, if so, can anyone share some sample code to learn how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by **function needs to include spring boot features**? Can you explain more what are you planning to achieve?

Comment: the SQS message needs to be transformed and posted as input to an API. I need retry so I am using spring cloud feign to make the API call from the lambda.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the API retying part. But if you need an SQS trigger for the lambda function, you can define it using CloudFormation. If that's what you need, I can share a sample CF.